# SocketTimeoutException explanations

Tags: android, web-services, sockets, socket-timeout-exception

I am using Webservice from my android mobile to upload Images. I don't need code or any of your work but just i want to know what is SocketTimeoutException.. not all times only few times i am getting the following Exception in Logcat.

Is this meaning of sockettimeout in server side or it may due to my mobile network problem and it can't reach for long time.

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to www.myserver.com/ (port 443) after 180000ms: isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:232) at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:171) at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884) at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:117) at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectRawSocket(SocketConnector.java:160) at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:79) at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143) at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185) at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128) at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341) at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330) at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248) at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437) at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114) at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:245) at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218) at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:223) ... 26 more ::

Comment: Read this: It may helps you to understand. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7360916/5241603

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608499/getting-java-net-sockettimeoutexception-connection-timed-out-in-android)