# Setting Timeout for JAX-RS 2.0 / Resteasy Client on Jboss

Tags: java, rest, jersey, resteasy

I want to set a request timeout for each invocation rest client. Currently I have this:

```
    private Client clientBuilder() {
    return new ResteasyClientBuilder()
            .establishConnectionTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .socketTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
            .register(ClientRestLoggingFilter.class)
            .register(ObjectMapperContextResolver.class);
}
```

Problem is, that probably don't work for other methods than get.
Whats more, socket Timeout is not timeout for reading full response, but for individual packets. [socketTimeout and connectionTimeout information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360520/connectiontimeout-versus-sockettimeout)

I am looking solution for RestEasy similar like following in jersey:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientProperties;

ClientConfig configuration = new ClientConfig();
configuration.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
configuration.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 1000);
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(configuration);
```

Answer (score 4):

As explained on jboss v7.3 by [redhat website](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.3/html-single/developing_web_services_applications/index) :

> The following ClientBuilder specification-compliant methods replace certain deprecated RESTEasy methods:
>
> - The **connectTimeout** method replaces the **establishConnectionTimeout** method.
>
>   - The **connectTimeout** method determines how long the client must wait when making a new server connection.
> - The **readTimeout** method replaces the **socketTimeout** method.
>
>   - The **readTimeout** method determines how long the client must wait for a response from the server.

So this should be good for your case:

```
    private Client clientBuilder() {
        return new ResteasyClientBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
            .register(ClientRestLoggingFilter.class)
            .register(ObjectMapperContextResolver.class);
    }
```