# How to detect end of Http request?

Tags: c#, html, parsing, request

I am creating a Http request parser. I am getting data in chunks (byte array) and parsing it simultaneously. I want to know the condition of detecting end of http request. The request may or may not contain message body.

Thanks

Comment: haven't looked it up, but I think two subsequent line-endings indicate the end of the request

Comment: This question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824451/detect-end-of-http-request-body

Comment: This somewhat begs the question why you're writing your own request parser when .Net has a perfectly good one built in?

Comment: @PhonicUK: because it's a great learning experience?

Comment: ...and the .net one behaves quite badly under stress?

Comment: @Randoms, fair enough then =)

Comment: @PhonicUK: Using .Net parser, how can i create a http request and again get the whole data(http request headers and message body) in form of string or byte array, so that i can send it over my sockets which i am using to send and receive data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three different ways:

- content-length header (number of bytes following the headers)
- chunked encoding (content length unknown at start of request, chunked encoding will indicate when the end is reached)
- connection closed by server (http "0.9")