# Page infinitely loading when connecting to my python web server

Tags: python, webserver

I've written a simple http web server using python but I've noticed that when I connect to it, the html page appears in the browser window but the indicator in the chrome tab continues to spin and the server receives empty strings. This continues until I click the 'X' to stop loading the page. Could someone please explain why this is happening and how to fix this. Also, if http headers are wrong or I'm missing important ones please tell me. I found it very difficult to find information on http headers and commands.

You find the code [here](http://txt.do/1826).

[Link to image of network tab](http://i60.tinypic.com/t9juxl.png)

Console output:

Socket created

Bound socket

Socket now listening

Connected with 127.0.0.1:55146

Connected with 127.0.0.1:55147Received data: GET / HTTP/1.1

Host: localhost

Connection: keep-alive

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0
.8

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36

DNT: 1

Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch

Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6




Parsing GET command

Client requested directory /index.html with HTTP version 1.1

html

/index.html

## Reply headers:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Server: Max's Python Web Server/1.0

Cache-Control: max-age=600, public

Connected with 127.0.0.1:55148

Received data:

Received data:

Received data:

Received data:

Comment: All indents are missed in your sorces, isn't it? We can't read python code without indents)

Comment: What does your browser's dev tools' network tab say?

Comment: @vp_arth Sorry, I didn't realise that indents are removed on the website I used previously. I've added a new link to a different website which keeps indents and has syntax highlighting.

Comment: @lmc I've added a link to and image of my network tab. Though I'm not hugely experienced with browsers and networking, I don't see anything that looks unusual compared to other sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fault is how you think about sockets:

`socket.recv` will wait forever for data from clients

You don't need a loop here.
However, your requests will be limited by `recv` param.
But if you want to allow any size request,
you should detect the end of data by **HTTP** specification.

For example, if you wait headers only, double linefeed will mean they ends.
And size of body(for **POST** method for example) should be passed with `Content-length` header as I know.

You issue is same as in this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824451/detect-end-of-http-request-body)
And google for HTTP Specifications, if you want to make correct HTTP server.