# Detect the end of an HTTP Request in Java

Tags: java, http, httprequest

Im trying to design a Java proxy program, but my java program has issues reading an entire HTTP request.

I used the `InputStream` object `isObj` to try to obtain data:

```
isObj.read(byteBuff)
```

But this often results in the data not getting read completely. i.e in case of a POST request, sometimes, the HTTP headers alone are read while the POST data is not read. So, I tried to use the below to read the data fully.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while((len=isObj.read(tempBuff))>0){
    baos.write(tempBuff,0,len);
}
byte[] byteBuff=baos.toByteArray();
```

However, this method also blocked at the `isObj.read(tempBuff)` function.

Tried another method using the DataInputStream like:

```
DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(isObj);
byte[] byteBuff=new byte[8196];
dis.readFully(byteBuff);
```

This also blocked at the `readFully()` function.

I read through and came across this

[Detect end of HTTP request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824451/detect-end-of-http-request-body)

which indicates that the reason is that there is no way we can identify when the data will get over(unless it is for a response). And it asks us to use the Content-Length header to detect the final length. Is this absolutely the only way to read HTTP Requests? Or is there any other library which does this automatically?

Comment: Mandatory mention of the actual specifications: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Apache's HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) for this. The HttpCore library offers a [DefaultHttpRequestParser](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/io/DefaultHttpRequestParser.html) which returns a [HttpRequest](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpRequest.html) instance with methods to get headers and fields from the request.

Comment: Its a good suggestion, although HttpClient specifically isn't really relevant to this question. Its about receiving a request, not sending one ;)

Comment: I'm trying to go through HttpComponents and it usually deals with the client side and not what to do at a server side. As @Gimby mentioned is there anything which can let me handle receiving a request.

Comment: You actually can parse HTTP Requests with it, as shown under section 3.1.3 in http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/tutorial/html/advanced.html

Comment: You should update your answer with relevant information.