# Extract data from a put request in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server

i am trying to send a put request to simple server in ruby with data.

```
curl --request PUT 'http://localhost:2000/api/kill' --data "c=19"
```

my server implementation is:

```
require 'socket'      

server = TCPServer.open(2000)
loop do 
  socket = server.accept
  while(line = socket.gets)
    p line
  end
  socket.close
end
```

i want to extract the data from the request. Currently it only prints the following.

```
"PUT /api/kill HTTP/1.1\r\n"
"User-Agent: curl/7.35.0\r\n"
"Host: localhost:2000\r\n"
"Accept: */*\r\n"
"Content-Length: 4\r\n"
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
"\r\n"
```

Any help regarding how to extract c=19 sent as data

Comment: Your ports are all different, btw

Comment: @Vaibhav You shouldn't ask interview test questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

`gets` is waiting for a newline. `curl` isn't sending one, `c=19` being the last thing that goes through the wire.

Also, you can't use `while line`, because `line` will never be false until the connection breaks, and `curl` will not break the connection, as it expects a response.

Look at "[Detect end of HTTP request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824451/detect-end-of-http-request-body)" about how the server is supposed to know when the request body ends. There are several cases to consider in order to be fully spec-compliant, but the method that should work most of the time, detecting `Content-Length`, is not terribly difficult.

Still, I suggest you let a library (e.g. Rack) take care of parsing the request, it is trickier than it looks.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
require 'socket'      

server = TCPServer.open(2000)
loop do 
  socket = server.accept
  line = ""
  until line == "\r\n"
    line = socket.readline
    if line.match /Content\-Length\:\s(\d+)/
      length = $1.to_i
    end
  end  
  line = socket.read(length)        
  socket.puts "The data was: #{line}"
  socket.close
end
```

It uses `"\r\n"` to detect the end of the header, and gets the length of the body from "Content-Length". It then uses that length to get the data via `read`

And note that the matching `curl` request is:

```
curl --request PUT 'http://localhost:2000/api/kill' --data "c=19"
```

Comment: Are you sure `read_nonblock` is a good idea? It works wonders when you are doing something else and it is in a loop; but won't this give you just partial data unless the connection is lightning-fast? In this case, I'd rather use plain `read`

Comment: @Amadan, I think you are right - and that `read` is the better option. I've modified my answer to use `read` instead of `read_nonblock`. Thank you